# WPF Label: Using the tooltip of the underlying Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Label which lays on top of Rectangles. These Rectangles have individual Tooltips. I want to show the Tooltip of the underlying Rectangle and ignore the Tooltip of the Label, how can I do this in wpf/c#.

Comment: Please share the code and other details to under your question. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004591/wpf-c-sharp-statusbar-label-content-from-current-controls-tooltip

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the labels to `False` so that the rectangles will receive the input from the mouse instead of the label.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly, what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it's har to tell how you actually want it to do

I would simply use the same method for the Tooltips

```
<Label Name="L1" ToolTipOpening="ToolTipMethod">
<Label Name="L2" ToolTipOpening="ToolTipMethod">

private void ToolTipMethod(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might want something like this:

[image]

This is just in pure xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
               ToolTip="Rectangle 1"
               Fill="Red" />

    <Label Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Label"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="50"
           Height="30"
           Background="LightBlue"/>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
               ToolTip="Rectangle 2"
               Fill="IndianRed" />

    <Label Grid.Column="1"
           Content="Label"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="50"
           Height="30"
           Background="LightBlue"/>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2"
               ToolTip="Rectangle 3"
               Fill="Red" />

    <Label Grid.Column="2"
           Content="Label"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Width="50"
           Height="30"
           Background="LightBlue"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course you can work out better ways on how to position the labels and defining their size to get what you want, this is merely an example.